# "many_to_many" if one of the foreign keys is unique string

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 2 main tables: `articles` and `tags`. They have "many_to_many_ relationship via `articles_to_tags` table. A thing is that a key of `tags` via which `articles` and `tags` are connected is of type `string`. On the level of database they look as follows:

```
tags:
  - id
  - name (unique)

articles
  - id
  - title
  - body

articles_to_tags:
  - article_id
  - tag_name /* !! */
```

On the level of Ecto:

```
  # articles_to_tags


  @primary_key false
  schema "articles_to_tags" do
    belongs_to(:article, Article)
    belongs_to(:tag, Tag, references: :name, foreign_key: :tag_name, type: :string)
  end
```

Even though I've filled out a database with test data that's assigns some tags to an article, in my project an article still has 0 tags:

```
article = Repo.get(Article, 123) |> Repo.preload(:tags)
IO.puts("*** article tags len: #{length(article.tags)}")
```

Why?

I've tried to play with `join_keys`, and it's turned out to be confusing and hasn't resolved the issue:

```
schema "articles" do
    # ................

    many_to_many(:tags, Tags, join_through: ArticleToTag,
      join_keys: [
        tag_name: :name,         # 'name' of which table?
        article_id: :id          # 'id' of which table?
      ]
    )
```

How to fix it?

Joining the tables via "tag.name" instead of "tag.id" is a requirement.

Comment: JFYI it is common practice to give your schema "singular" names, e.g `MyApp.Article` instead of `MyApp.Articles`. It is not going to break anything though so don't worry about it.

Comment: @PeacefulJames JFIY you can't see what   the modules for the models named

Comment: Oh yes, good point. I see you actually have `Article` in the question. I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3

> :join_keys - ..,expects a keyword list with two entries, the first being how the join table should reach the current schema and the second how the join table should reach the associated schema.

So you should try doing this in your Articles schema:

```
schema "articles" do
    # ................

    many_to_many(:tags, Tags, join_through: ArticleToTag,
      join_keys: [
        article_id: :id          # 'id' of current schema
        tag_name: :name,         # 'name' of associated schema
      ]
    )
```